# Javascript "Show/Hide", very simple, and Multiplatform/Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I need a script show/very simple and you can use css transition, was using the jquery below but it has a certain delay in mobile devices, and I can't use transitions with him, I'll use the script many times on my site, so I wanted something simple to keep the site and that works both in browser mobiles, and desktops.

**Very Delay in Safari/ IE10 Mobile**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // show and hide menu top
        $(".dropmenu").hide();
        $(".dropbtn").show();

    $('.dropbtn').click(function(){
    $(".dropmenu").slideToggle(0);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

For the "click"  event to fire you need mousedown and mouseup an element, which on mobile browsers results in an 300ms delay.
If you go directly for `touchstart` it'll fire in no time :)

```
$(function(){

    // show and hide menu top
    $(".dropmenu").hide();
    $(".dropbtn").show();

    $('.dropbtn').on('touchstart click',function( e ){
        if(e.type=='touchstart') $(this).off('click');
        $(".dropmenu").slideToggle(0); // or use just .toggle();
    });

});
```

<sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Touch_events</sub>